# How to create a generator without a counter and indices?

Tags: python

I'm studying Python and I have a problem with the task.

We need to create a generator that takes 2 non-decreasing sequences and combines it into 1 non-decreasing sequence and returns it.

I solved the task through indexes and counter, but now there is a new problem. The generator shows an error if the sequence is out of order.

I'd appreciate it if you could help with the task.

Here's my code:

```
def mer(seq1, seq2):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(seq1) and j < len(seq2):
        if seq1[i] <= seq2[j]:
            yield seq1[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            yield seq2[j]
            j += 1
    while i < len(seq1):
        yield seq1[i]
        i += 1
    while j < len(seq2):
        yield seq2[j]
        j += 1
#check
def x():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
for i in mer(x(), x()):
    print(i, end=" ")
```

Comment: Can you be clearer with your question? You'd like to raise an error if either of the sequences is out of order, regardless of the other sequence?

Comment: Could you post a [mcve]? Your code won't run because the generator (`x()`) doens't have a `len`. Given the input `[1, 2, 3]` what do you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 0):

To merge pre-sorted sequences you can use `heapq.merge`:

```
from heapq import merge

def x():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
for i in merge(x(), x()):
    print(i, end=" ")
```

This outputs:

```
1 1 2 2 3 3
```